# What makes Adobe Reader display the "Signed" panel?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am signing PDF files server side with PHP and I want Adobe Reader to display this banner on my resulting PDF saying that the file has been successfuly signed :

[image]

I am using code from the **TCPDF library** to achieve this (I had to modify some code to fit my needs).
I based my work on these two documents from Adobe official documentation : [doc1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and [doc2](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf).

What I do :

1. Add the signature tags to the PDF file :

   ```
   // The ID of the last object of the PDF + 1 
   $sigobjid = preg_match_all("/([0-9]+) 0 obj/", $pdfdoc, $output_array);
   $sigobjid = end($output_array[1]) + 1;
   // Write the signature tags where needed
   $index_to_write = strrpos($pdfdoc,"endobj") + 6;
   $signature_tag = PHP_EOL . $sigobjid . ' 0 obj '. PHP_EOL . '<< /Type /Sig /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached '. TCPDF_STATIC::$byterange_string . ' /Contents<'.str_repeat('0', $tcpdf->get_signature_max_length()).'> >>' . PHP_EOL . 'endobj';
   $pdfdoc = substr_replace($pdfdoc, $signature_tag, $index_to_write, 0);
   ```
2. Compute and replace the **ByteRange**
3. Compute the hash of the file like this :

   ```
   $hash_result = hash('sha256', $pdfdoc);
   ```
4. Sign the resulting hash client side with forge.js : I use a PFX file that I parse and then create a **PKCS7** using the data contained in the PFX.
5. Send the hash to server.
6. Add the signature to the PDF in the **Content** tag.

**EDIT :** Thanks to @mkl comment I also tried to reference my Sig object with the AcroForm with the following lines into my PDF file :

```
11 0 obj
<< /Type /Sig /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached /ByteRange[0 2846 14590 507] /Contents< ...
endobj
12 0 obj
<</AcroForm 11 0 R >>
endobj
```

It is not working either. How should I fill the AcroForm field ?

The resulting PDF is readable by Adobe Reader but the blue banner does not appear, why ?

Comment: Can you share the PDF?

Comment: I'm not really into PHP but the code you show seems to focus only on creating a signature dictionary. Do you elsewhere also create a signature form field (or locate an empty existing one) and assign your signature dictionary as value of it? If you don't, then that is (at least part of) the problem, to make PDF viewers find a signature dictionary, it must be value of a signature field in the PDF AcroForm structure.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the answer ! I didn't know about AcroForm structure as it's barely mentionned in the documentation. I tried to just add a reference like this <</AcroForm 11 0 R >> with 11 being the ID of my Sig object but it does not work either, nothing appears. Could you tell me what the AcroForm should contain ?

Comment: *"I didn't know about AcroForm structure as it's barely mentionned in the documentation."* - well, subsection 12.7 (more than 30 pages) of ISO 32000-1 (which you referred to as "doc1") deals with AcroForm forms. Please read it. As a hint: the **AcroForm** entry in the document catalog shall point to the interactive form dictionary. In this you should set **SigFlags** correctly and have **Fields** set to an array of your form fields, i.e. at least one signature field whose **V** value is your signature dictionary, whose **T** value is the field name, and whose **AP** value contains appearances.

Comment: Thanks ! I meant that there is no examples, that's weird for a type of files widely used. I'm not sure about those fields because I have PDF files that I signed myself and that display the blue banner without having those fields.

Comment: *"I have PDF files that I signed myself and that display the blue banner without having those fields."* - that's very unlikely. Can you share a sample?

Comment: My workplace blocks all uptobox kind of websites, I'll upload example files tonight. I have also some encrypted part in my PDF, they are stream object embedded in FlatDecode fields, perhaps the fields that you talk about could be in those streams but I can't read it ? Many thanks by the way you're saving my internship haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it myself so for these who were wondering, you need those fields :

```
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog /AcroForm << /Fields [12 0 R 13 0 R] /NeedAppearances false  /SigFlags 3 /DR << /Font << /F1 14 0 R >> >> /DA (/F1 0 Tf 0 g) /Q 0 >> /Perms << /DocMDP 11 0 R >>
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
...
endobj

11 0 obj
<< /Type /Sig /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached /ByteRange[0 3153 14897 922] /Contents<...> /Reference [ << /Type /SigRef /DigestMethod /SHA256 /TransformMethod /DocMDP /TransformParams << /Type /TransformParams /P 2 /V /1.2 >> >> ] >>
endobj

12 0 obj
<< /Type /Annot /Subtype /Widget /Rect [510.236220 572.598661 552.755906 615.118346] /P 4 0 R /F 4 /FT /Sig /T (Signer Name) /Ff 0 >>
endobj

13 0 obj
<< /Type /Annot /Subtype /Widget /Rect [510.236220 572.598661 552.755906 615.118346] /P 4 0 R /F 4 /FT /Sig /T (Signer Name) /Ff 0  /V 11 0 R >>
endobj

14 0 obj
<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /F1 /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >>
endobj
```

You basically need :

- 1 **Font** object (obj 14 in this example)
- 1 **Sig** object (obj 11) containing the signature in the 'contents' field
- 1 **Page** object (obj 4)
- 2 **Annot** object (obj 12 and 13) referencing the first page object with the **P** flag and the Sig object with the **V** flag
- 1 **AcroForm** field inside your main **Catalog** (obj 1) referencing your 2 Annot object in the Fields array, referencing your font in the **F1** field, and your signature in the **DocMDP** field.

**EDIT :** The **DocMDP** field is not mendatory and only one **Annot** is needed. No **Font** required either.